# How to sum and array's interval?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

```
import java.util.stream.*;

int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
int sum = IntStream.of(array).sum();
```

> in this case "sum" = 15, but what if i wanted to sum the numbers from index[0] to [3]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case Use `Arrays.stream():` and entre the interval you need

**Exmple :**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;



    public class SumInterval{


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    int[] a = {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5};
                                     // entre index 
                                     int sum = Arrays.stream(a, 0, 2).sum();
                                    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        }


    }
```

output :

```
`The sum is` 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-int-int-):

```
// end index is exclusive
int sum = Arrays.stream(array, 0, 4).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a limit to the stream:

```
int sum = IntStream.of(array).limit(4).sum();
```